# CKEditor with jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I had some textareas on a page that used jquery.validate.  I added CKEDITOR to those textareas, and now the testers are complaining that when they make an error, the validator warns them that there is an error (because I do an updateElement on the editors before calling it), but the textareas don't get a red border any more.  Is there a way to fix that?  Is there a way to find the CKEDITOR instance in the errorPlacement function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered I was barking up the wrong tree using errorPlacement.  Instead, I added a highlight and unhighlight function:

```
      errorPlacement: function(error, element)
      {
        $(element).parent('div').prev().append(error[0]);
      },
      highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
      {
        $(element).parent().addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
      },
      unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
      {
        $(element).parent().addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ckeditor hides the textarea (`display:none`) and replaces it with an iframe with editable content. I think you should try to let the validation trigger a function that gives the iframe a red border if invalid.

I wrote a small working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5wJVu/1/ (works in firefox, but I stripped the cke-IE-support for this small example so might not work in IE...)

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
     for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();// to update the textarea
     }
     // setTimeout to let the validation complete first 
     // and then check for the .error classname.
     setTimeout(function(){
         var ta=$("#ckeditor");
         var cke=$("#cke_ckeditor");
         if (ta.hasClass('error') ){cke.addClass('error')}
         else{cke.removeClass('error')}
     },300);
     return true;
});
```

Comment: That was sort of my question - how do I find the thing I can add a red border around in the errorPlacement function.

Comment: Your solution isn't great, because you're using a timeout instead of the errorPlacement function, and also you're assuming I only have one textarea on the screen and I know its id, and as I stated in the question I have multiples.  But I think you're getting closer to what I need.

Comment: your highlight solution is indeed better and cleaner, too bad I didn't think of that!

Comment: Well, since I've got to award the bounty to somebody and I can't award it to myself, why don't you add the highlight solution to your answer and I'll give you the bounty?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't want to repeat your answer, but a bounty may also be rewarded to the person that helped you the most to get to the right solution. Since your own answer is marked as accepted people will read that first. My answer is only another solution that may or may not have helped you, I'll let you decide if it's worth the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these answers:

- [Using jQuery to grab the content from CKEditor's iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924145/using-jquery-to-grab-the-content-from-ckeditors-iframe)
- [using CKEditor with jQuery validation plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903504/using-ckeditor-with-jquery-validation-plugin-not-working)

You'll essentially do something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_editor() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.content.updateElement();
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, that doesn't answer the question.  I already do that, and the validation fails.  It just doesn't put a visual indication around the textarea that failed.

Answer (score 1):

That should solve the problem:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#cms-form").validate({
    event: 'blur',
    rules: {
      title: {required: true},
      content: {
        required: function(textarea) {
          CKEDITOR.instances[textarea.id].updateElement(); // update textarea
          var editorcontent = textarea.value.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, ''); // strip tags
          return editorcontent.length === 0;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```