# ckeditor data not being validated by jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I know there are loads of questions out there about this but I can't get this to work for the life of me. I have tried several solutions including [this](http://devlog.waltercruz.com/usando-ckeditor-e-jquery-validate-juntos), [the second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903504/using-ckeditor-with-jquery-validation-plugin-not-working) and [this](http://css.dzone.com/articles/using-jquery-validate-plugin), and I can't get the "required" message to appear.  The form still submits when the ckeditor field is empty.

I looked at the documentation [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#updateElement) and am able to pass the contents of the editor to an alert but am not experienced enough to know how to integrate this with the validation plugin.  I've spent so much time on this - can anyone please help?

Here is my current code, and I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BmZ93/1/

```
     $('#add-job').validate({
                rules: {
                editor1: {
                    required: function() 
                    {
                    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
                    }
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                Job_Title: "Required",
                Job_Location: "Required",
                jobid: "Required",
                Job_Cat: "Required",
                editor1: "Required"
                } 
        });
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here it is update your code with this

http://jsfiddle.net/rohanppatil/BmZ93/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add-job').validate({
    ignore: [],         
    rules: {
                editor1: {
                    required: function() 
                    {
                    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
                    }
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                Job_Title: "Required",
                Job_Location: "Required",
                jobid: "Required",
                Job_Cat: "Required",
                editor1: "Required"
                },
                /* use below section if required to place the error*/
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
                {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "editor1") 
                   {
                    error.insertBefore("textarea#editor1");
                    } else {
                    error.insertBefore(element);
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

Hope this will work I tested this in JSFIDDLE working fine

Comment: Just finished testing it out, it works! Thanks so much

Comment: @shrawan_lakhe Welcome

Answer (score 13):

You should change the value of `ignore` property which by default holds `:hidden` value. as `CKEDITOR` hides the textarea  jQuery validation doesn't validate the element:

```
ignore: []
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BmZ93/5/

Also note that you should return a boolean value in your `required` method, you don't. Here passing `true` suffices.

```
required: true
```

This is the updated code which also uses `errorPlacement` method for adding a border to the CKEDITOR wrapper, you can customize it according to your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-job').validate({
        rules: {
            'editor1': {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Job_Title: "Required",
            Job_Location: "Required",
            jobid: "Required",
            Job_Cat: "Required",
            editor1: "Required"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, $elem) {
            if ($elem.is('textarea')) {
                $elem.next().css('border', '1px solid red');
            }
        },
        ignore: []
    });
});
```

Comment: But it won't call if the text area is touched right? We must edit it manually?