# Jquery validation not working with ckeditor

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, ckeditor

I am using jQuery to validate forms.. but when I use CKeditor and try to validate it using jQuery, it's not working.

Here is the snippet of HTML code

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="f3" id="f3" >
   <div class="col-xs-8">
       <textarea class="ckeditor" name="cktext" id="cktext"></textarea>
   </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Here is the form validation code

```
    <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#f3").validate(
            {
              debug: false,
                rules: { 
                    cktext: {                         
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 10
                    }
                 }
            });
        });
      </script>
```

FYI : jQuery validation working for other form fields expect the **ckeditor textarea** field

Any suggestions.. to get rid of this problem..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Finally i found the answer to my question...

I changed the value of ignore property which by default holds :hidden value. as CKEDITOR hides the textarea jQuery validation doesn't validate the element:

```
   ignore: []
```

Just i changed the validation script as follows..

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#f3").validate(
            {
                ignore: [],
              debug: false,
                rules: { 

                    cktext:{
                         required: function() 
                        {
                         CKEDITOR.instances.cktext.updateElement();
                        },

                         minlength:10
                    }
                },
                messages:
                    {

                    cktext:{
                        required:"Please enter Text",
                        minlength:"Please enter 10 characters"


                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML snippet is

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="f3" id="f3" >
     <div class="col-xs-8">
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="cktext" id="cktext"></textarea>
    </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

As i found this answer in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763216/ckeditor-data-not-being-validated-by-jquery-validation)

Thanks to all...

Comment: Thanks it's helpful  +1.

Comment: Found helpful in validating ckeditor field validation, thanks

Comment: Still working for me in 2022.  Key behind all these answers seems to be getting CKEditor to update the base field using `updateElement()` +1

Answer (score 7):

I took the previous answer and fleshed it out with an actual CKEditor, so that you can see what needs to be done to copy the contents of the CKEditor into your textarea *before* submit.

The key bits are this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
    $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function (instance) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("keyup", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("paste", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("keypress", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("blur", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("change", CK_jQ);
    });
});

function CK_jQ() {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}
```

Which I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17104424/312208) to a different but similar question.

The other error you have is misspelling `minlength` in your rules object.

This is what it looks like working: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/QcJ57/

Comment: +1, and you should make sure the OP is tagged with [tag:jquery-validate] so others browsing the category won't miss this one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: [],
    // with this no hidden fields will be ignored E.g. ckEditor text-area
});
```

I observed the validation was working on 2nd submit. The reason is, `ckEditor` hides the actual text area and puts an iframe as an editor instance, and on submit it pushes the content to the text area. Which means, the validation on the `TextArea` gets fired on stale data. To fix this problem, I am updating my `TextArea` on the text change of the editor instance.

```
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on('change', function ()
        {
            var editorName = $(this)[0].name;
            CKEDITOR.instances[editorName].updateElement();
        });
    }
```

Comment: it helped a lot...now the problem is the validation message "This field is required" is not removing on entering the contents in textarea

Answer (score 2):

we can validate ckeditor using jquery validation by using the following piece of code.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>

$("#myForm").validate({
   ignore: [],

     rules:{
            firstname:{
            required:true
        },
    editor1: {
       required: function(textarea) {
       CKEDITOR.instances[textarea.id].updateElement();
       var editorcontent = textarea.value.replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, '');
       return editorcontent.length === 0;
     }
               }
     },messages:{
            firstname:{
            required:"Enter first name"
        }

     }
   });
```

for more information about validation click here [**http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/129/validate-ckeditor-using-jquery-form-validation**](http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/129/validate-ckeditor-using-jquery-form-validation).

Answer (score 2):

Bydefault Ckeditor field is not validate using required rule. We have to create custom validator method for this -

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('ckrequired', function (value, element, params) {
    var idname = jQuery(element).attr('id');
    var messageLength =  jQuery.trim ( CKEDITOR.instances[idname].getData() );
    return !params  || messageLength.length !== 0;
}, "Image field is required");
```

And most importantly blank the ignore array -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f3").validate({
        ignore : [],
        rules: {
        cktext:{    
            ckrequired:true
        }
    }
            });
        });
      </script>
```

Now you are all set.

Comment: it's working , thanks @aishwarya

Answer (score 1):

**Validate ckeditor with out jquery validation plugin...**

```
$("form").submit( function(e) {
      var messageLength = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, '').length;
      if( !messageLength ) {
          alert( 'Please enter a message' );
          e.preventDefault();
       }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers are good, they provide solutions for validation only on submit button, here some code for **reactive validation of the ckeditor fields, like default jquery validation do.** Put this on your *ckeditor/config.js*:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
    var instance = e.editor;
    instance.on("change", function (evt) {
        onCKEditorChange(evt.editor);
    });
    //key event handler is a hack, cause change event doesn't handle interaction with these keys 
    instance.on('key', function (evt) {
        var backSpaceKeyCode = 8;
        var deleteKeyCode = 46;
        if (evt.data.keyCode == backSpaceKeyCode || evt.data.keyCode == deleteKeyCode) {
            //timeout needed cause editor data will update after this event was fired
            setTimeout(function() {
                onCKEditorChange(evt.editor);
            }, 100);
        }
    });
    instance.on('mode', function () {
        if (this.mode == 'source') {
            var editable = instance.editable();
            editable.attachListener(editable, 'input', function (evt) {
                onCKEditorChange(instance);
            });
        }
    });
});

function onCKEditorChange(intance) {
    intance.updateElement();
    triggerElementChangeAndJqueryValidation($(intance.element.$));
}

function triggerElementChangeAndJqueryValidation(element) {
    element.trigger('keyup');
}
```

**Bonus**: If you are using custom submit buttons and handlers for your form, now **you don't need to explicitly call** `CKEDITOR.instances["yourtextarea"].updateElement();` before sending form via ajax to your server.

Also dont forget to call:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: []
});
```

My CKeditor: version:"4.5.4",revision:"d4677a3"
Doc for ckeditor events: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor. It was hard to find right doc on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Simple snippet worked for me.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_input_name');

$( "#form_id" ).submit( function( e ) { 
     //in case, if didn't worked, remove below comment. This will get the textarea with current status
    //CKEDITOR.instances.textarea_input_name.updateElement( ); 
    var messageLength = CKEDITOR.instances['textarea_input_name'].getData( ).replace( /<[^>]*>/gi, '' ).length;
    if( !messageLength )
    {
        alert( 'Please fill required field `Text`' );
        //stop form to get submit
        e.preventDefault( );
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //editor is not empty, proceed to submit the form
        return true;
    }
} );
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

On initialize ckeditor:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
        for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function () {
                this.updateElement();
            });
        }
    });
```

Also don't forget to call them on validation plugin initialize:

```
ignore: []
```

But the most important of all which may seem insignificant is that the `required class` should be placed in the textarea input

Answer (score 0):

in ckeditor5 you can't just get the data automatically. you have to use their function to get the data, below is the source code which is used to validate ckeditor5 with jquery.

/// below code is only requires if you dont have ckeditor5 textbox in page and you want to intialize the textbx to particular id like id="**#content**"

```
 var editorTextarea;
    ClassicEditor
        .create (document.querySelector ('#content'))
        .then (editor => {
           editorTextarea = editor;
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        });

/ ** This way I invoke validations, where "content" is the name of my textarea: 
 <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="content" id="content"><?= $data["page"]->content;?></textarea>
    </div>
** /


// if have already intialized the ckeditor5 textbox than you just have to replace **editorTextarea** to with your editor name
$ .validator.addMethod ("ck_editor", function () {
       var content_length = editorTextarea.getData (). trim (). length;
       return content_length> 0;
   }, "Please insert content for the page.");



   $ ("# form_page_edit"). validate ({

       ignore it:[],
       rules: {
           title: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 6,
               maxlength: 255
           },
           url: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 6,
               maxlength: 255
           },
           content: {
               ck_editor: true
           }
       }
   });
```

this helps you to validate ckedior5 with jquery validation

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me like below. I added "`return`".

```
rules : {
    subject: {
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        required: function()
        {
            return CKEDITOR.instances.description.updateElement();
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to put a submit button in your form:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

The form is only validate when is submitted.

Check example on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/800/

Comment: i am using the submit button with type="submit".. in my form i forgot to post.. it..