# SubmitHandler jQuery Validate Submit Empty CkEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate, ckeditor

Hi I used [**jQuery Validation**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate my form before submit it.

And I intercept submit handler in this way:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   <![CDATA[

        $(function() {
            $( "#_${sec_form}_id" ).validate({
                errorElement: "span",
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });

          $.validator.addMethod(
                "validator",
                function(value, element, regexp) {
                    if(value != null && value.trim()!=""){
                        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                        return re.test(value);
                    }else{
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                "Inserire un valore coerente."
            );
        });
    ]]>
   </script>
```

In that form I have some **Ckeditor** fields, but when I submit form, I lose all edits to **ckeditor** fields.

If I delete my submit handler, all works.

Have you any idea about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy your CKEditor fields' values to an actual textarea before submitting so that your error will be ignored.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function () {
    $.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function (instance) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("keyup", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("paste", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("keypress", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("blur", CK_jQ);
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].document.on("change", CK_jQ);
    });
});

function CK_jQ() {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}
```

To try this, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/QcJ57/

For more information check this question: [Jquery validation not working with ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248918/jquery-validation-not-working-with-ckeditor)