# jQuery Form Validator with CKeditor 4.x validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, jquery-form-validator

I am using [jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html) library for my validation and its working fine as per my expectations.

Now I have integrated WYSIWYG Editor called as [CKeditor 4.x](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/) and I want to make `required` validation. But its not working for me. Here is what I have done so far.

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" rows="10" cols="80" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg-required="Please Enter Blog Title." ></textarea>

<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.4/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script> 

CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );


$.validate({     
    ignore: [],   
    form: '#admin-blog-form',
    inputParentClassOnError: 'admin-form-error',
    scrollToTopOnError: false,
    debug: false,
    rules: {

        description: {
            required: function () {
                CKEDITOR.instances.description.updateElement();
            },

            minlength: 10
        }
    },
    messages:
    {

        description: {
            required: "Please enter Text",
            minlength: "Please enter 10 characters"


        }
    }



});

</script>
```

As you can see I have a form id called as `admin-blog-form` and my CKeditor id is `description`.

I am trying to use `rules` variable by following [jquery-validation-not-working-with-ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22292841/6829420) answer but its not working for me using this library.

I have also tried to follow documentation and trying to write [custom-validators](http://www.formvalidator.net/#custom-validators) using below code.

```
$.formUtils.addValidator({
        name: 'requiredCKEditor',
        validatorFunction: function (value, $el, config, language, $form) {
            return false;
        },
        errorMessage: 'You have to answer with an even number',

    });

<textarea name="description" id="description" rows="10" cols="80" data-validation="requiredCKEditor" ></textarea>
```

But this also is not working for me. I have read libary's other documentation pages but nothing helped me to integrate this.

Can someone guide me how can I achieve this ?